# publish junit test result report from parent's workspace

Tags: jenkins, junit, rspec, jenkins-plugins, post-build-event

I have a parent job and two child jobs in jenkins. The workspace shared by the child jobs resides within the parent job.
Now the child jobs are producing a Junit RspecFormatted logs (job1.xml and job2.xml), which is getting stored in the parent's job workspace.
I am trying to refer giving the full path:
$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/{parent-job}/{folder a}/{folder b}/{folder c}/test-results/job1.xml in the post build result section but the build fails to find this path.

Note: I am able to print the file in the `Execute Shell` section with this path

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about the issue, can you give me more details?

By the way if i understood your needs, you can use the:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

To get variables like TRIGGERED_JOB_NAME and NUMBER, so you can build the PATH

$JENKINS_HOME/workspace/${TRIGGERED_JOB_NAME}/{folder a}/{folder b}/{folder c}/test-results/job1.xml

What about folder a/b/c, where are these variable valued?

You can also simply pass these information as parameters and than use them as variables to dynamically build the path...

Let me know if it's clear and if it helped...